# The plan that I want to give [to] you. Direct, Indirect object in attributive clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses, direct-objects, indirect-objects

I don't know the grammar rule I must apply in the following sentences. Do I need to add *to*?

1. Here is the book that I want to give [to] you.
2. Here is the plan that I want to give [to] you.
3. Here is the plan that I want to introduce [to] you.

> The plan that I want to give you has already worked out for me.

Someone might think that the idea if the plan is to give listener away in exchange for something.

Comment: Native speakers often dispense with the preposition ***to*** in your examples where the verb is ***give***, but rarely if ever with ***introduce***. Note that you *can't* discard ***to*** in an "imperative" construction, such as the command/request *Give the book **to** me!* in "standard" English, but dialectally it's at least *possible* (particularly in the construction *Give it me!*, but never with an explicitly-named target such as *Give the book me!)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's all about the relative clauses :)

Comment: @Araucaria: Regardless of what grammarians might say, I've no problem with, for example, *Have you got the money I lent you yesterday? Well, **give it me** then, and I'll buy us a beer!* But even though I don't fully understand the thrust of your comment, I would never ask *Can you please **explain it me**?* without ***to***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd agree (and I'm sure the grammarians would to. *Give it me* is perfectly grammatical for many speakers, including me. The interesting thing about it is that it's only ok with a pronoun, not, as you noted, with a full noun phrase headed by a noun * *Give the grammar book me*. The difference between *introduce* and *give* here, is that we can say *I want to give you the book* and *I want to give the book to you*. When the noun phrase *the book* is deleted because it has been relativised (it's already represented by the antecedent of the relative clause), ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...  those become "the book *I want to give you ____ *"  and  "the book *I want to give ___ to you*". But with *introduce*, we can only say *I want to introduce the plan to you*, not *I want to introduce you the plan*, and so we get the following "the plan *I want to introduce ____ to you*" (perfectly fine) and * "*the plan *I want to introduce you ___* (ungrammatical) respectively. Interestingly, your *give it me* type example ends up with "the book *I want to give ___ you*". The structure's different, 'cuz the gap's in a new place, but the surface form's  the same!

Comment: @Araucaria: Somewhere on ELU, JLawler said (usually, *imperative*) *give [object] [noun/pronoun]* is only valid because the subject ends up *possessing* the thing given. But personally I don't have a problem with *Open me the door, please*, even though he says this is "incorrect" by his lights.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sure many speakers use that. I'm not sure how I feel about it. It seems ok if I squint at it ...

Answer (score 1):

"give you" and "give to you" mean roughly the same thing, so they are interchangeable in your sentences (although as FumbleFingers said, native speakers would drop the "to").

However "introduce you" and "introduce to you" have slightly different implications, therefore the "to" is needed in sentence #3.