# This is the gift that my dad sent (to) me

Tags: ellipsis

This is the gift that my dad sent me on my birthday.

Vs

This is the gift that my dad sent to me on my birthday.

Is to required?

Also

Presenting you guys, the trailer of the film.

Vs

Presenting to you guys, the trailer of the film.

Is to required?

Comment: Similar: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166413/the-plan-that-i-want-to-give-to-you-direct-indirect-object-in-attributive-cl

Answer (score 1):

*to* is not required following *sent*. *to send* (as well as *to give*, *to lend*, *to feed*, etc.) can take an indirect object (without a preposition) as well as a direct object. If there is only one object, then it’s a direct object* - the item that is actually being sent, as in:

> He sent a gift

But if there are two, then the order is [indirect object - person receiving the item being sent] [direct object - the item being sent], as in

> He sent me a gift.

I don’t think *to* would be incorrect in this context, but a prepositional phrase normally follows a direct object, so this would be better:

> He sent a gift to me.

Your first example sounds better without the *to*.

As for your second example, neither sounds right to me. As with *to send*, if *to present* takes one object with no preposition, it is assumed to be a direct object. So “presenting you guys” sounds like “you guys” are being presented- that is wrong.

“Presenting to you guys” is grammatical but not idiomatic. Normally when you say you are presenting something, it is understood that “you guys” is the audience. You could simply say:

> Presenting the trailer of the film.

This is more idiomatic. You could tack on “to you guys” at the end of that sentence but it’s not necessary.

*EDITED to note- what I said about a verb that can take both an indirect object (with no required preposition) and a direct object - that it takes a direct object if there is only one object specified- is not true for all verbs. “I fed a fish” means “I gave food *to* a fish”, so in this case *a fish* is the indirect object. However, “to send” must take a direct object and if only one object is used, it has to be a direct object. “She sent me” means she made me go somewhere- so *me* is the direct object.